# how to use a javascript array for react select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I want to pass a java script array as options to the react-select in JSX, but this throws a

> TypeError: options.filter is not a function

My code is

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: '',
      optionArray: {}
    }
    this.publishedMsgSet = [];
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDataReceived = this.handleDataReceived.bind(this);
  }

  handleDataReceived(data) {
    this.state.optionArray = [
      { value: 'suggestion', label: 'suggestion' },
      { value: 'abcabc', label: 'abcdabc' },
    ];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.optionArray));

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        styles={this.props.muiTheme.name === 'dark' ? customStyles : {}}
        name="form-field-name"
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={this.state.optionArray} <-- is this a valid statement
      />

    );
  }
```

How can I pass the optionArray values as options to the select tag?

Comment: What is `Select`? From what package? Note: `optionArray` is not an array on first render (you have an object in your initial state). Also, **do not mutate state directly after the initial state is set**!

Comment: Your initial state is initializing an Object --> `optionArray: {}` . Therefor `filter` is not a valid method.

Comment: Your `optionArray` is currently an object (`{}`). Try with an array instead (`[]`), e.g. `[{ label: 'foo', value: 1}, { label: 'bar', value: 2 }]`.

Comment: `optionArray` is not an array at initialization, neither `handleDataReceived` is run to change its type to Array.

Comment: I initialized optionArray: [{ value: 'foo', label: 'foo' }] like this and I want to load data from my database, but the data doesn't load until I select foo from select.

Comment: @ish_i94 - Please answer Li357's question in the first comment above: What `Select` is that? There's more than one. Is Tholle correct that you're using `react-select` (specifically, [this one](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), since there could be multiple projects with that name)?

Comment: I'm using 'Select from 'react-select';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining initial value of optionArray as an **Object**, not an array:

```
this.state = {
  selectedOption: '',
  optionArray: {} // This in an object
}
```

Must be:

```
this.state = {
  selectedOption: '',
  optionArray: [] // Empty array
}
```

And, this is wrong:

```
handleDataReceived(data) {
    this.state.optionArray = [
      { value: 'suggestion', label: 'suggestion' },
      { value: 'abcabc', label: 'abcdabc' },
    ];

}
```

You shouldn't mutate the state directly, you should call **setState()**:

```
handleDataReceived(data) {
  this.setState({
    optionArray: data // Expecting "data" is an array
  });      
}
```

To pass a prop, this is OK:

```
options={this.state.optionArray}
```

It will pass a prop called optionArray. Select should be expecting an array, because is trying to call filter.